# Ubuntu: How to listen to music streams on the web without Flash (by finding the IP address of the streaming server?)

Tags: flash, music, streaming, ip, internet-radio

How can I find the ip address of a music streaming service in Ubuntu?

Specifically: How can I do this for:

- 106KMEL : http://www.iheart.com/live/293/?autoplay=true
- Hot97 : http://www.hot97.com/HotStream/

Why I'm asking: These streaming services still require you to use Flash. But Flash requires heavy CPU work (see for example the process "plugin-container", in the case of Firefox). That's climate change due to stupid software and I'm not OK with that.

So the idea was:

1. Find the direct IP of the web radio station's streaming server
2. Use Rythmbox (or any other steaming application) to listen to these streams

Comment: The IP-address alone is easy to find out (for instance by checking the output of netstat while listening), but does not help much. You need the full URL for the stream AND the stream has to be in a format that a generic player can handle. I don't expect that the stations you linked to supply such a stream. If you are desperate enough, you can look at firefox's network data by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+k or run a sniffer like wireshark and analyse the communication between the flash player and the server, but I wouldn't have too much hope that it will work without flash...

Comment: Thanks! So: In the case of 106KMEL (=iheart.com), I wasn't able to get to the stream (easily enough, at least). In the case of Hot97, I found an URL which can be trimmed down to: http://5883.live.streamtheworld.com/WQHTFMAAC. This will download the streaming file, so all you'd have to do is open that *.part file (.flv/Flash format) with your player (ie. VLC) as soon as it has *started* downloading. The only problem then is: even when you hit "Pause" in your player, the download obviously continues. That makes only sense for 8hour-streaming.